# Radial Sweeping of a Brush

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a way to fill something using a radial sweep of a defined brush in WPF. I'm going to break down what I want in a series of images in an attempt to make it clear.

Let's say I define a brush in WPF that looks like so:

[image: Brush]

I then want to use a slice of that brush like so:

[image: Brush with Slice]

And tile it across the radius of a circle as shown:

[image: Tiling the Radius]

Finally, in order to fill the shape, I would like to sweep the brush across all angles of the circle, providing me with a result similar to this:

[image: Sweeping the Circle]

In this particular case I'm attempting to make concentric circles. I know I could achieve this using RadialGradientBrush but this is an obnoxious solution as in order to precisely control the width of my concentric circles I would need change the number of radial stops based on the size of the circle. To make it worse, if the circle size changes, the radial stops will not change unless I use some kind of converter based on the circle width/height.

I was hoping for a clean solution to do this maybe with paths or something but any other suggestions for making circle slices of controlled size is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How about this to draw a few concentric circles by use of a Brush?

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="1"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7"/>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9"/>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="11" RadiusY="11"/>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the concentric circle case, combining Clemens's solution with a converter allows for  precisely sized circles whose width can be changed dynamically and the amount of circles is set to as many will fit in the allowed area.

```
class SizeSpacingToCircleGroupConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null) return values;
        var input = values.OfType<double>().ToArray();
        if (input.Length != 3) return values;

        var width = input[0];
        var height = input[1];
        var spacing = input[2];

        var halfSpacing = spacing / 2;
        var diameter = width > height ? height : width;

        var lineCount = (int)Math.Floor((diameter / (2 * spacing)) - 1);
        if (lineCount <= 0) return values;

        var circles = Enumerable.Range(0, lineCount).Select(i =>
        {
            var radius = halfSpacing + (i * spacing);
            return new EllipseGeometry() { RadiusX = radius, RadiusY = radius };
        }).ToArray();

        var group = new GeometryGroup();
        foreach (var circle in circles) group.Children.Add(circle);

        return group;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Rectangle Height="{StaticResource Diameter}" Width="{StaticResource Diameter}">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush Stretch="None">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" Thickness="{StaticResource SpacingDiv2}"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SizeSpacingToCircleGroupConverter}">
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Diameter}" />
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Diameter}" />
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Spacing}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

In my case I'm just using doubles defined in my resource dictionary but I could easily use a binding from a view model.

I still won't mark anything as the accepted answer however because the question was about a tiled radial sweep which could be useful for other reasons.